# encryption decryption inside spark udf , using JKS file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, encryption, user-defined-functions, jks

I have requirement to encrypt decrypt using jks file inside spark udf.
Running my application using spark-shell I am getting below error

```
by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: CDA_KEYSTORE_PT140.jks
```

I know as udfs are treated as black box by spark so any file inside it would not be read as hdfs file so I tried to send copy of file to local working directory of each executor using

```
/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/bin/spark-shell --files CDA_KEYSTORE_PT140.jks
```

my udf is as below

```
def impl2(col1:String): String ={
var pilotCrypto=new PilotCryptoImpl
    pilotCrypto.setKey1("sensitive data")
    pilotCrypto.setKey2("sensitive data")
    pilotCrypto.setKey3("sensitive data")
    pilotCrypto.init()
    EncryptionUtil.setCrypto(pilotCrypto)
    val psg = new IvParamSpecGenerator(true)
    val crypto = new JceCryptoImpl
    crypto.setKeystoreURL("CDA_KEYSTORE_PT140.jks")
    crypto.setKeystoreType("JCEKS")
```

My complete code is as below which I am running using spark-shell command. Code is inside .scala file

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rank
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, udf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType

def createDataframeFromSql(hc: SparkSession, sql: String): DataFrame = {

    var df = hc.sql(sql)
    return df
  }
  
def impl2(col1:String): String ={

    var pilotCrypto=new PilotCryptoImpl
    pilotCrypto.setKey1("EbT5a8Fuq")
    pilotCrypto.setKey2("aYt2gv6R")
    pilotCrypto.setKey3("9bFp3Gz4k")
    pilotCrypto.init()
    EncryptionUtil.setCrypto(pilotCrypto)
    val psg = new IvParamSpecGenerator(true)
    val crypto = new JceCryptoImpl
    crypto.setKeystoreURL("CDA_KEYSTORE_PT140.jks")
    crypto.setKeystoreType("JCEKS")
    crypto.setKeyAlias(EncryptionUtil.decryptHex("sensitive data"))
    crypto.setKeyPassword(EncryptionUtil.decryptHex("sensitive data"))
    crypto.setCipherTransformation("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
    crypto.setAlgorithmParamSpecGenerator(psg)
    crypto.setEncodeBase64(true)
    crypto.init()
    val string_to_decrypt = col1
    var encryptedBytes1 = col1.getBytes
    var decryptedBytes1 = new String(crypto.decrypt(encryptedBytes1))
    decryptedBytes1
  }
  
  
  

  def processdata(): Unit = {
    try {
      val hc = SparkSession.builder.appName("HivetoSpark").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir" , "namenode/apps/hive/warehouse").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
      import hc.implicits._
      hc.sql("""set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true""")
      hc.sql("""set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict""")
      hc.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
      hc.sql("""set hive.merge.tezfiles=true""")
      hc.sql("""set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=256000000""")
      hc.sql("""set hive.merge.size.per.task=256000000""")
      hc.sql("""set hive.merge.sparkfiles=true""")
      val start = System.currentTimeMillis()

     val impl2udf = udf(impl2 _)
      var query1 =s"""select * from table"""
      var fraud_trn_df1 = createDataframeFromSql(hc, query1)
      fraud_trn_df1.show(5,false)

      val fraud_trn_df2 = fraud_trn_df1.withColumn("FT_PRIM_NUM_AMT_decr",impl2udf(col("ft_prim_num_amt")))
      val fraud_trn_df3 = fraud_trn_df2.withColumn("FT_SECONDARY_NUMBER_AMOUNT_decr",impl2udf(col("ft_secndy_num_amt")))
      fraud_trn_df3.show(5,false)

      val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
      val runTimeInSec = (end - start) / 1000.0
      println(s"runTimeInSec: ${runTimeInSec}sec")
    }
```

I am calling processdata in the end.

```
stackrace is as below

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (string) => string)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply_133$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:232)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: CDA_KEYSTORE_PT140.jks
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:593)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
        at com.telus.framework.crypto.impl.jce.JceCryptoImpl.init(JceCryptoImpl.java:78)
        at $line28.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.impl2(<console>:56)
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:59)
        at $line29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:59)
```

Comment: I think that you are still using `crypto.setKeystoreURL("CDA_KEYSTORE_PT140.jks")``. Should not you change that for the full qualified path (including "hdfs://")?

Answer (score 1):

That URL is missing the protocol (as the error message stated).

It should be written in the following format:

```
crypto.setKeyStoreURL("hdfs://[path]/CDA_KEYSTORE_PT140.jks")
```

If you have to run with a local file, then use:

```
crypto.setKeyStoreURL("file://[path]/CDA_KEYSTORE_PT140.jks")
```

With Spark I prefer HDFS files, since they are easier to reach by all workers. Otherwise, with local files, you will have to copy it to all worker nodes.

Comment: I have tried giving HDFS path and full local path of edge node but they are still showing same error.

Comment: Can you update the code shown in the question and also past the whole stacktrace? That might help.

Comment: `hdfs://` isn't a valid file protocol here